# When using nodejs soap lib, AxiosError: socket hang up

Tags: node.js, soap, axios

```
const soap = require('soap');


const url = `http://xxx.xxx.1.101:8888/bmss/wd/SystemService?wsdl`

soap.createClient(url,(err:any, client:any) => {
            if (err) {
            console.error('Error creating SOAP client:', err);
            return;
            }

});
```

AxiosError: socket hang up, error occurred while trying to see the value of the createClient.

method:get
http://xxx.xxx.1.101:8888/bmss/wd/SystemService?wsdl
http://xxx.xxx.1.101:8888/bmss/wd/SystemService?wsd=1
Both work well. When it works as a postman.

I don't know why I can't just use the soap library. I even specified timeout, but the results are the same.
Even the easy-request-soap works well.

But I want to use soap to approach client.myFunction and develop it.
If there are people who have developed nodejs TS environment Soap, please advise.

```
error creating SOAP client: AxiosError: socket hang up
    at connResetException (node:internal/errors:787:14)
    at Socket.socketOnEnd (node:_http_client:519:23)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:526:35)
    at Socket.emit (node:domain:488:12)
    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1589:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
  code: 'ECONNRESET',
  config: {
    timeout: 0,
    xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
    xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
    maxContentLength: -1,
    maxBodyLength: -1,
    env: { FormData: [Function] },
    validateStatus: null,
    headers: {
      Accept: 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml,text/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
      'User-Agent': 'node-soap/1.0.0',
      'Accept-Encoding': 'none',
      'Accept-Charset': 'utf-8',
      Connection: 'close',
      Host: 'xxx.xx.xx.xx:8888'
    },
    url: 'http://xxx.xx.xx.xx:8888/bmss/ws/SystemService?xsd=1',
    method: 'get',
    data: null
  },
  request: <ref *1> Writable {
    _writableState: WritableState {
      highWaterMark: 16384,
      length: 0,
      corked: 0,
      onwrite: [Function: bound onwrite],
      writelen: 0,
      bufferedIndex: 0,
      pendingcb: 0,
      [Symbol(kState)]: 34357356,
      [Symbol(kBufferedValue)]: null
    },
    _events: [Object: null prototype] {
      response: [Function: handleResponse],
      error: [Function: handleRequestError],
      socket: [Function: handleRequestSocket]
    },
    _eventsCount: 3,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    _options: {
      maxRedirects: 21,
      maxBodyLength: 10485760,
      protocol: 'http:',
      path: '/bms/ws/SystemService?xsd=1',
      method: 'GET',
      headers: [Object],
      agent: undefined,
      agents: [Object],
      auth: undefined,
      hostname: '***',
      port: '*',
      nativeProtocols: [Object],
      pathname: '/bmss/ws/SystemService',
      search: '?xsd=1'
    },
    _ended: true,
    _ending: true,
    _redirectCount: 0,
    _redirects: [],
    _requestBodyLength: 0,
    _requestBodyBuffers: [],
    _onNativeResponse: [Function (anonymous)],
    _currentRequest: ClientRequest {
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 7,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      outputData: [],
      outputSize: 0,
      _contentLength: 0,
      _hasBody: true,
      _trailer: '',
      finished: true,
      _headerSent: true,
      _closed: false,
      socket: [Socket],
      _header: 'GET /bmss/ws/SystemService?xsd=1 HTTP/1.1\r\n' +
        'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml,text/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8\r\n' +
        'User-Agent: node-soap/1.0.0\r\n' +
        'Accept-Encoding: none\r\n' +
        'Accept-Charset: utf-8\r\n' +
        'Connection: close\r\n' +
        'Host: ***\r\n' +
        '\r\n',
      _keepAliveTimeout: 0,
      _onPendingData: [Function: nop],
      agent: [Agent],
      socketPath: undefined,
      method: 'GET',
      maxHeaderSize: undefined,
      insecureHTTPParser: undefined,
      joinDuplicateHeaders: undefined,
      path: '/bmss/ws/SystemService?xsd=1',
      _ended: false,
      res: null,
      aborted: false,
      timeoutCb: [Function: emitRequestTimeout],
      upgradeOrConnect: false,
      parser: null,
      maxHeadersCount: null,
      reusedSocket: true,
      host: '****',
      protocol: 'http:',
      _redirectable: [Circular *1],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kNeedDrain)]: false,
      [Symbol(corked)]: 0,
    },
    _currentUrl: 'http://***/bmss/ws/SystemService?xsd=1',
    [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey !
I'm running into the exact same problem.
Have you found a solution ?
Thanks :)